# CAST: diferença entre "(String) arg" e "String.class.cast(arg)"

Tags: java, cast

Gostaria de saber se existe diferença entre:

```
String a = (String) arg;
```

e o *cast* da classe:

```
String a = String.class.cast(arg);
```

Uma vez, ouvi dizer que utilizar o *cast* estático da classe é mais performático, isto é verdade?

Comment: Acho que vc pode fazer bechmarking e descobrir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ambos executam a mesma tarefa, porém a chamada versão "estática" gera mais bytecode (mais overhead em tempo de compilação).

Na pratica ambos executam o cast usando a instrução bytecode:

```
CHECKCAST java/lang/String
```

A diferença que o código gerado pela versão "estática" obtém o tipo declarativamente, no caso String.class, fazendo uma chamada de [Class.cast(Object)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.cast%28java.lang.Object%29)

**código de referencia:**

```
public class CastTest2 {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Object arg = "Test";

        String explicitCast = (String) arg;

        String explicitDynCast = String.class.cast(arg);

    }
```

bytecode gerado para o cast direto:

```
   L1
    LINENUMBER 10 L1
    ALOAD 1
    CHECKCAST java/lang/String
    ASTORE 2
```

bytecode gerado para o cast "estatico":

```
   L2
    LINENUMBER 12 L2
    LDC Ljava/lang/String;.class
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Class.cast (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    CHECKCAST java/lang/String
    ASTORE 3
```

Sendo assim:

```
LDC Ljava/lang/String;.class
```

A instrução acima retorna uma instancia de Class

que por sua vez, chama o método cast, retornando um Objeto:

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Class.cast (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

e implicitamente faz o Cast para o Type, Class T.

```
CHECKCAST java/lang/String
```

ps: O fato o qual chamo "estatico" e como pode ser visto no bytecode que a chamada a Class.cast(object) é feita usando a instrução INVOKEVIRTUAL e não INVOKESTATIC.

Answer (score 3):

Como dito pelo Felipe nos comentários, para questão de comparativo de performance basta você fazer um *benchmarking* simples das duas abordagens.

Neste exemplo foi usado o [Metrics](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics), versão `3.1.0`. Caso use [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), basta adicionar esta dependência:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Outras considerações:

- JRE 1.8 *update* 45
- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Rodado no Eclipse Luna, release 2, versão 4.4.2, Build id 20150219-0600

Foram feitos **10000** *casts* de objetos para `String`, tanto usando o *cast operator*, quanto usando [`cast(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-).

Abaixo estão os trechos usados para cast:

- usando *cast operator*

```java
static void usingCastMethod() {
    final Object obj = "string";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        final String str = String.class.cast(obj);
    }
}
```

Resultado: 629.19 milisegundos

- usando [`cast(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-)

```java
static void usingCastOperator() {
    final Object obj = "string";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        final String str = (String) obj;
    }
}
```

Resultado: 3065.02 milisegundos

**Obs.**: o resultado é apenas para comparativo, apenas para vermos que há sim diferença em performance.

Pelo resultado podemos perceber que há diferença significativa, ou seja, podemos concluir que isto não é tratado de forma diferente pelo compilador.

Agora, vamos verificar como ficou o *bytecode* gerado nas duas abordagens:

- usando *cast operator*

```
  static void usingCastMethod();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #104                // String string
       2: astore_0
       3: iconst_0
       4: istore_1
       5: goto          21
       8: ldc           #106                // class java/lang/String
      10: aload_0
      11: invokevirtual #113                // Method java/lang/Class.cast:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      14: checkcast     #106                // class java/lang/String
      17: astore_2
      18: iinc          1, 1
      21: iload_1
      22: sipush        10000
      25: if_icmplt     8
      28: return
```

- usando [`cast(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-)

```
  static void usingCastOperator();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #104                // String string
       2: astore_0
       3: iconst_0
       4: istore_1
       5: goto          16
       8: aload_0
       9: checkcast     #106                // class java/lang/String
      12: astore_2
      13: iinc          1, 1
      16: iload_1
      17: sipush        10000
      20: if_icmplt     8
      23: return
```

Pelo bytecode podemos ver que de fato usando *cast operator* é mais oneroso, se você verificar cada instrução na [especificação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/) verá em detalhes o porque disso.

Em resumo é devido ao fato de java saber o tipo apenas em tempo de execução, então ele tem que se virar para garantir ao máximo possível que não dê um `ClassCastException`. Já na outra abordagem, mesmo gerando mais *bytecode*, você já deixou explícito o tipo que espera, se não for ele (`isInstance(Object obj)`) uma `ClassCastException` será lançada, sem a JVM buscar mais informação para tentar o *cast*

Já sabendo que em termos de performance há diferença, existem vantagens e desvantagens? Consigo agora lembrar apenas quando usamos genéricos:

- para evitar *warning* em tempo de compilação quando estamos usando genéricos (e não apenas `String`), ou seja, em vez disto:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T cast(final Object o) {
    return (T) o;
}
```

Prefira usar isto:

```java
public <T> T cast(final Class<T> clazz, final Object o) {
    return clazz.cast(o);
}
```